# Place a smal Image in the right top corner of a ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, contentpresenter

I have a normal ComboBox.

[image]

Now I want to place a small Image 16x16px in the right top corner.

[image]

I've try this code:

```
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="211" Height="37">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                    <Image Source="/WpfApplication6;component\accept_16.png" Width="16" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

But it only shows the Image, and not the Combobox...

Comment: I am really sorry I don't have time, but what you want to style is ToggleButton of Combobox... you have to create style for ToggleButton and set it to Template property of ToggleButton within Combobox ControlTemplate. If you want me to do it I will this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the `ComboBox` and `Image` inside of a `Grid`, and align the `Image` to the Top Left corner. Then you won't be replacing a rather complex `ControlTemplate` with an overly simplified one:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

For reusability, make a UserControl out of it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then Insert it into your XAML as many times as you like:

```
<local:UserControl1/>
```

If however you insist on retemplating the ComboBox, consider modifying a complete template. Consider the following "default" Controltemplate (and dependencies) for ComboBox:

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="4,4,21,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RoundCorners="false" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Placement}">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="RenderFocused" TargetName="Border" Value="true"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                            <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                            </Canvas>
                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </Popup>
                        <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I should elaborate about the template: By overriding the ControlTemplate with just a ContentPresenter, you are not displaying the ItemsPresenter (or other default visuals associated with the ComboBox control).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This way I've also thought about, but I want to make all the combo boxes and then it is too cumbersome

Comment: Make a UserControl out of it, then it is reusable. I will edit my answer above to explain.

Comment: My image appears pixelated when I add it to my WPF. I am wondering why that is and what can I do it fix it? Thanks!